# Does ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair guarantee a single thread?

Tags: c#, async-await

Is it inherently part of `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` to guarantee the same thread in the background, for `ExclusiveScheduler`?

For example, with an SDK that I want to run on a background thread, but the calls may be some time apart. e.g:

```
var csp = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair();
...

// Start SdkStuff() - this may not take long
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SdkStuff(), 
    Cancel.Token, 
    TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, 
    csp.ExclusiveScheduler);

// And then a few days later, without having any tasks 
// given to it, is this second SDK call GUARANTEED to be
// on the same thread?
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MoreSdkStuff(), 
    Cancel.Token, 
    TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, 
    csp.ExclusiveScheduler);
```

Is `SdkStuff` guaranteed to run on the same thread as `MoreSdkStuff`?

Edit:
I'm not merely interested in the tasks running exclusively, they must also be on the same thread - which although the latter is a way of executing the former I need to *know* it will be on the same thread. The documentation doesn't specify that, as far as I can see. If you have some, please point it out.

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I did. I read the whole sentence that describes what it does. It does not answer my question.

Comment: Feel free to quote the bit that specifically answers my query about thread guarantees. I can't see it.

Comment: The documentation talks about exclusive and concurrent guarantees. It doesn't say anything about running on the same thread. That should be clear enough that it doesn't.

Comment: So why did you ask if I've read the docs if they don't answer the question?

Comment: They do; if there were a guarantee of running on a single thread the documentation would have mentioned it.

Comment: I think that's naive. It has a single sentence of documentation. That's hardly full, is it? I'm not going to assume every bit of documentation I read is comprehensive. The very nature of my question is that I can see it doesn't make the guarantees - but that I'm a little surprised by it, as it could be useful (and would be to me). 

I appreciate your answer below, but not the snide "I shouldn't have asked a question" attitude. That's not very StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to be snide. I was just asking.

Comment: Oh thank you. Nice to know ;) Thanks for your time.

Comment: I assumed the downvote was yours which combined with your first comment = snide! So apologies for that assumption.

Comment: No, not my downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation talks about exclusive and concurrent guarantees. It doesn't say anything about running on the same thread. That should be clear enough that it doesn't make such guarantees.

If you want to ensure the code runs on the same thread consider using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive"). Then you an do this:

```
var els = new EventLoopScheduler();

IDisposable subscription1 = els.Schedule(() => SdkStuff());
IDisposable subscription2 = els.Schedule(() => MoreSdkStuff());
```

You can even schedule at a specific time using this library.

```
IDisposable subscription2 = els.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromHours(24.0), () => MoreSdkStuff());
IDisposable subscription3 = els.Schedule(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(8.0), () => MoreSdkStuff());
```

Calling `.Dispose()` on any of these subscriptions will cancel the pending action.

You can even schedule recurring tasks:

```
IDisposable subscription4 =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(2.0), els)
        .SelectMany(x => Observable.Start(() => SdkStuff()))
        .Subscribe();
```

Or even:

```
IDisposable subscription5 =
    els
        .Schedule(TimeSpan.FromHours(1.0), a =>
        {
            MoreSdkStuff();
            a(TimeSpan.FromHours(0.5));
        });
```

This last one starts in 1 hour and then executes every 30 minutes after that.

The key part of this is that `EventLoopScheduler` ensures that all of the operations occur on the one thread.